# Not finding channel by name

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I tried `let message = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == 'channel-name')` and it results undefined. channel is a guild channel if I hover over it in vscode but I used console.log and it's undefined.

Comment: I have tested your code and it does work as intended.  Make sure you don't make any typos in your channel names.  Channel names are lowercase.

Comment: It could be because I use a var name in the channel name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to get a channel do

> message.guild.channels.cache.get("Channel ID")

Pretty much more easier to use

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems I have for you:

1. The channel doesn’t exist (self explanatory)
2. You are not caching the channel

```js
//To cache the channel do this:
await message.guild.channels.fetch();
//…find code, etc
```

3. Your bot doesn’t have access to the channel.
   If you don’t see the bot in the channel's members list, then the bot clearly doesn’t have access. Make sure to give the bot view channel permissions in the channel.

Comment: The code you put needs the ID. I need to find the ID. The channel exists and the bot is an admin.

Comment: Are you caching the channel? The `fetch()` is to cache **ALL** channels in the server, not to find it. You can then find it within the cache.

Comment: @WasteofSpaceYT Not sure why you accepted the other answer if you wanted to find a channel by its name. The accepted one only works with IDs, while this one is correct and solves your issue.

Comment: I don't remember 100% but I'm pretty sure the other one doesn't use promises.